# Usage of "is to " vs " is at"

Tags: grammar

We can say

> The hospital is to the left side of the restaurant

Can we say

> The hospital is at the left side of the restaurant

?

Answer (score 1):

With USA English, "to" or "on" would fit here. We are describing location with reference to a specific object/location. Both words imply you would see (or arrive at) the restaurant first, and from there find your way to the hospital. "At" implies a stand-alone location you could reach directly. The hospital is "at" the intersection of Fourth Avenue and Main Street, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, "to the left" would specify a direction, while "at the left" would specify a position. So, for example,
"Move to the left side of the room."
"Sit at the left side of the room."

In practice, in some examples like yours, the expressions are interchangeable.